# Logo only in some slides

Tags: beamer, nodes, ticks, logos

I am using a presentation available on Overleaf ["TU Chemnitz Beamer Presentation Template"].

A circle has been created in each slide and through the code shown here the logo is inserted inside the circle (so in all slides).
How can I put the logo only in some slides, for example slide number 1 and slide number 5?

Sorry if I'm not clear it's my first time asking

```
\node  at (logopos) {\includegraphics[width=1\beamer@logoradius]{TUCgraphics/cause.png}} ;
```

Comment: This code snippet looks like it's from a bigger tikzpicture. It is very hard to tell what it is doing if we don't have the whole picture. Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)-provided overlay specification for `\includegraphics<overlay spec>[<options>]{<image>}`:

```
\node at (logopos) {%
  \includegraphics<1,5>[width=\beamer@logoradius]{TUCgraphics/cause.png}%
};
```